# Unable to properly update Flot graph on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, graphing

I have a graph that is properly generated when the page loads. That code is:

```
<body>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),
[ { data: %s } ],
{ xaxes: [ { mode: 'time' } ],
  yaxes: [  ] })
});
</script>
```

Which works fine. I have a button that executes jquery and makes a request to get a new json data structure. I've validated that the json being returned is indeed proper json. I'm attempting to graph the result with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $("#button").click( function()
           {
             //alert('button clicked');
             $.ajax({
                url:  '/graph',
                type: 'POST', 
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    start_date: $('#start_date').val(),
                    end_date  : $('#end_date').val(),
                    ticker    : $('#ticker').val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
                var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
                $.plot(placeholder,
                  [ { data: result } ], 
                    { xaxes: [ { mode: 'time' } ],
                      yaxes: [  ] });  
             }
            });
          }
      );
});
```

Which redraws the graph, but it's empty and the y-axes is the default -1.0 through 1.0 and the x-axes is a single time entry of 00:00:00.

I've tried to use the setData() and draw() method calls but they don't fix the issue.

There are no javascript errors being thrown as shown by firebug. 
So, what am I doing wrong?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the response is valid?  Your dataType is 'html', so unless you're doing something with a script tag, then the response is just a string.  If you're returning JSON directly, then you need to use dataType 'json'.

Comment: Wow, nice catch! That fixed it. Damn! I thought the dataType was for the POST Request, not the dataType of the response data, which would normally be set by the Content-Type header in the response ...